# Fey Beast Tamer, Scaling of your Fey Beast companion

Tags: dnd-4e, character-levels, animal-companions, theme

How does the companion chosen, via Theme: Fey Beast Tamer, scale with the PC it is bonded with?

I am a lv01 Wood Elf (archer) ranger (14 AC before armor) with the theme Fey Beast Tamer and have chosen an Owlbear. The AC of the Owlbear is 14 at LV01 but when I level my char to 4 or 8, the AC aswel as other NAD defenses do not change.

Is this an error? Or are the companions just really weak?

I read something about DDI not calculating the values correctly, or not at all, but without a proper source I can not defend this notion to my DM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Fey Beast Tamer companion scales up with your level. It's Defenses, and to-hit value are all a value *plus* your level.

> Your fey beast companion’s level is equal to yours, and its hit points, defenses, and attack values are determined by your level, as noted in its statistics.

And as an example here is the header of the Trained Blink Dog:

> HP your bloodied value
>
> Initiative equal to yours
>
> AC 15, Fortitude 13, Reflex 13, Will 13
>
> Perception equal to yours +2
>
> Speed 7
>
> low-light vision

The important thing is that the AC and NADs are their values *plus* your character level. That means at L1 the Blink Dog's AC is 16, and at 30 it's 45. And yes, DDI isn't going to calculate this correctly.